# Is it possible to pass class name as a parameter in Java?

Tags: java

I have following code:

```
private void startLesson(String input) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartovayaAktivnost.this, OsnovnayaAktivnostORM.class);
    intent.putExtra("vybor_razdela", input);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I want to launch different activities depending on parameter, is there a simple solution to pass a class name like

```
 private void startLesson(String input, String activityname) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartovayaAktivnost.this, activityname.class);
    intent.putExtra("vybor_razdela", input);
    startActivity(intent);
} //I know it's not gonna work
```

or the only way is to use embranchments like

```
    private void startLesson(String input, String activityname) {
    if (activityname.equals("OsnovnayaAktivnost")) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartovayaAktivnost.this, OsnovnayaAktivnost.class);
        intent.putExtra("vybor_razdela", input);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (activityname.equals("OsnovnayaAktivnostORM")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartovayaAktivnost.this, OsnovnayaAktivnostORM.class);
        intent.putExtra("vybor_razdela", input);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use '.getName()' on the class type, so for instance 'StartovayaAktivnost.class.getName()'.

Comment: yes it's possible.. and then you can do everything almost with your class object in that method which receive passed class object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a class as a parameter. Consider the following:

```
private void startLesson(String input, Class activityname) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartovayaAktivnost.this, activityname);
    intent.putExtra("vybor_razdela", input);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can then call your method as

```
startLesson("input", Main.class);
```

The same way as they're using classes as their parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(activityname);
Intent intent = new Intent(StartovayaAktivnost.this, myClass);
intent.putExtra("vybor_razdela", input);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, activityname should be the full class name.

Comment: It is the class name, not the class that should be passed according to the question.

Comment: activityname will still be a string that represents the class name, however, this solution only works with the full class name (package.subpackage.ClassName).

Answer (score 1):

You already have answers that show you solutions. I am more curious about your use-case though. For a similar situation I created a map of strings to classes of a certain base type. When passing *activityName* to that map, I would find the activity, or not. This gives you more control over what kind of classes are allowed to be loaded in this situation. In your scenario it would be harder to limit what kind of classes can be passed into `Intent`. But I imagine they have to adhere to certain rules that make up an activity.

Something like:

```
Map<String, MyBaseActivityType> activities
```

If you need new instances of the activity class every time, you can modify it a bit, I haven't given that part much thought.

But don't use *[reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html)* unless you really really need it. It gets messy quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer while trying at random:

```
private void startLesson(String input, String activityname) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartovayaAktivnost.this, Class.forName(activityname));
        intent.putExtra("vybor_razdela", input);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```